# Use of Fubini's Theorem

Tags: definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $f(m,n)$ be a real valued function for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that 
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\lvert f(m,n)\rvert\le\frac{1}{n^2}
$$
for each positive integer $n$. Use Fubini's Theorem to prove
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(m,n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n).
$$
Proof: In Fubini's Theorem we have two measure spaces $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B},\nu)$ with $\nu$ being complete. Then if $f$ is integrable over $X\times Y$ with respect to the product measure $\mu\times\nu$ then $f(x,\cdot)$ is integrable over $Y$ with respect to $\nu$ and

$$
\int_{X\times Y} f\,d(\mu\times\nu)=\int_X \int_Y f(x,y)\,d\nu\,d\mu.
$$

1.) So based on the statement of my problem, I want to let both my measure spaces be the counting measure space, which is a complete measure space.

2.) Then I need to show that $f$ is integrable on $X\times Y$ wrt $\mu\times\nu$ in order to conclude that $f(x,\cdot)$ is integrable on $Y$ wrt $\nu$. Do I simply observe that since 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n)\le\left\lvert\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n)\right\rvert\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty \lvert f(m,n)\rvert\le\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$ 
we have $f(m,n)$ integrable and then proceed to iterate the integral in both orders to show my desired result? It seems like the given condition already implies that $f(x,\cdot)$ is integrable on $Y$ wrt $\nu$.

---

Since $\nu$ is complete and $f$ is integrable then by Fubini's Theorem, I can show that 
$$
\int_{X\times Y}f(m,n)\,d(\mu\times\nu)=\int_X\left(\int_Yf(m,n)\,d(\nu)\right)\,d(\mu)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(m,n).
$$

Similarly, since $\mu$ is complete and $f$ is integrable then by Fubini's Theorem, I can show that 
$$
\int_{X\times Y}f(m,n)\,d(\mu\times\nu)=\int_Y\left(\int_Xf(m,n)\,d(\mu)\right)\,d(\nu)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n).
$$
Finally since $f$ is integrable we know $
\int_{X\times Y}f(m,n)\,d(\mu\times\nu)<\infty$ so
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(m,n)=\int_{X\times Y}f(m,n)\,d(\mu\times\nu)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n).
$$

Comment: The combination of Fubini/Tonelli tells you that if any of the three are finite: $\int_X \int_Y |f(x,y)| dy dx$, $\int_Y \int_X |f(x,y)| dx dy$, $\int_{X\times Y} f(x,y) d\pi$ (where $\pi$ is the product measure), then all three corresponding integrals of f(x,y) are equal.

Comment: The trick is the fact that both of the measure spaces are complete and I actually use Fubini's Theorem twice, once for each iteration. I show that $\int_{X\times Y}=\sum_m\sum_n$ and that $\int_{X\times Y}=\sum_n\sum_m$. Since the two sums have a common finite value, they are equal.